# Javascript variable scope. What's going on here?

Tags: javascript, scope

Can someone explain why I'm getting `"global value"` logged when I execute this code?

```
function printFoo() {
    console.log(foo);
}

var foo = 'global value';

(function () {
    var foo = 'local value';
    printFoo();
})();
```

I understand that when resolving a variable, javascript starts at the innermost scope and searches outwards, so why is it not printing the local value here if it's defined earlier in the scope chain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `foo` in `printFoo` is the global, not the local. JavaScript's scope rules are lexical and based on where the function is *created*. That is, to tell what's in scope for `printFoo`, you look at where `printFoo` is created (not where it's used) and look at what's in scope in that place.

Variables are, according to the specification, technically properties of an object, specifically what the spec calls the *variable binding object* (VBO) for the execution context where the variable was created. The variable binding object also has a reference to the variable binding object of the *containing* scope, and so on outward until we reach the global object.

For instance, consider this code:

```
var globalVar;

function foo() {
    var fooLocalVar;

    return bar;

    function bar() {
        var barLocalVar;

        console.log(globalVar);
    }
}

globalVar = "testing";

var b = foo();
```

If we run that code, there will be two VBOs: The global object which contains `globalVar` (let's call that VBO1), and the VBO for the execution context created when we called `foo` (let's call it VBO2). Even though `foo` has returned, VBO2 still exists, because it's referenced by the `bar` function that was created when we called `foo`, and we still have a reference to that function via our `b` variable. VBO2 has properties for `fooLocalVar` and `bar` (and a couple of other things). VBO2 also has a reference to VBO1.

If we then did this:

```
b();
```

...then during the call to `bar`, a third VBO (VBO3) would exist which has a property called `barLocalVar` (and a couple of other things) and a reference to VBO2. During the call to `bar`, when we do `console.log(globalVar)`, the JavaScript engine looks at VBO3 to see if it has a property called `globalVar`. Since it doesn't, the engine follows the link to the next outer VBO (VBO2) and checks if *it* has `globalVar`. Since it doesn't, it looks at VBO1, finds it, and uses its value *as of that moment*. Since nothing continues to reference VBO3 when `bar` returns, VBO3 is eligible for garbage collection, but note that as long as we have `b`, VBO2 is kept in memory.

Now let's take it further:

```
var b2 = foo();
```

Now we have a *second* VBO related to calling `foo`, because we called `foo` a second time and kept a reference to something (the `bar` function, which we've remembered as `b2`). This is a different VBO that the one for our first call to `foo`, but it has properties with the same names, just different values.

VBOs are anonymous in code (you can't get access to the actual VBO itself, just its properties) with one exception: The global object, which is referenced by `this` at global scope, and which on browsers has a property, `window`, that it uses to refer to itself.

Comment: Shouldn't it be undefined then?

Because JS vars are hoisted, the code I'm running is equivalent to:

var foo;
function printFoo() {
    console.log(foo);
}
foo = 'global value';
(function () {
    var foo = 'local value';
    printFoo();
})();

Comment: @RubenSerrate: That's a good question. The answer is no, it shouldn't be `undefined`, because the function has an *enduring reference to the variable*, not a *copy* of the variable's value as of when the function was created. It uses the variable itself, and so like all variable accesses, it happens when you do it. So the var is declared, the function is created, you assign a value to the var, and then you call the function. This is the basis of closures. More (on my blog): [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Comment: @RubenSerrate: I've updated the answer to talk a bit more about how variables are resolved.

Comment: That's a great answer, thank you very much!! Just as your blog post!

It's so easy to achieve simple stuff with Javascript but it's also amazing how clever things can get!

Answer (score 1):

> "I understand that when resolving a variable, javascript starts at the
>   innermost scope and searches outwards"

That is true, but Javascript doesn't nest the scopes the way that you think.

Calling the `printFoo` function from another function doesn't mean that the `printFoo` scope is inside the scope of the calling function. As the `printFoo` is declared in the global scope, the only scope outside the function scope is the global scope.

To have the scope nested, you would declare the `printFoo` function inside the other function:

```
var foo = 'global value';

(function () {

    function printFoo() {
        console.log(foo);
    }

    var foo = 'local value';
    printFoo();
})();
```

Now the function will see the `foo` variable declared locally in the anonymous function instead of the one in the global scope.

Comment: Yep thanks, this makes it even more clear! Upvaoted :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you're creating a global variable (i.e. a property of `window` object).

That is, even if you call the whole variable in a named function declared before the global variable, since the function itself gets executed after global variable declaration, it will print `"global value"`.

Also check that current ECMA-Script standard (5.x) has function scope but other blocks won't create an inner scope. This is why you declare `foo` in the function's local scope but it won't affect `printFoo` `foo` variable printing.

### Why `foo` value is available from the function...

```
// Although this function is declared before
// even "foo" is declared and set, the function is executed
// once "foo" is set.
//
// JavaScript runtime will look for a "foo" variable in the local scope, and
// because it doesn't find it there, it looks in the global scope: bingo!
function printFoo() {
    console.log(foo);
}

var foo = 'global value';
```